# Appending an array of images inside for loop - swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I might be missing something really stupid here but can someone tell me why this isn't working?
nothing is getting added to the Array.

```
var goblin = NSImage[]()

for (var i = 2; i == 50; i++) {
   var imageString = "/Users/Neil/Developer/iOS Apps/Resources/Goblin/\(i).png"
   var image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: imageString)
   goblin.append(image)
}
goblin[0]
```

my files are just simply called 2.png, 3.png up to 50.png.
I'm just working in playground for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops in swift follow the same paradigm as `for` loops in C. That is, the CONDITION section must evaluate to `true` to allow the loop to follow another iteration. In your example code you seem to be aiming to achieve 49 iterations over the loop but you are starting the `i` counter at 2.

So on the first iteration the loop CONDITION section is evaluated by `2 == 50` which is `false`, therefor the loop is not executing even a single iteration.

Here is a simplification of the suggested solution:

```
var goblin = String[]()

for (var i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
    var imageString = "\(i).png"

    goblin.append(imageString)
}
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid, completely overlooked that.  Thanks Maxim!

Comment: @Maxim: How do I turn this String array into a single string so I can assign in to a text property of a label or something?

Comment: @Isuru I think you want to post this follow up as a new question on StackOverflow.